# Start a process with a name

Tags: linux, process, kill-process

Basically I want to dynamically start some processes which may create their own children processes, also I want to kill a certain group of processes I just created whenever I want. One way I could think of is to start processes with a name(to distinguish as a group), then use pkill to kill them by the name. The question is how to start a process with a name so that I can use pkill to kill them by the name? I am open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 21):

[How can I start a process with a different name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153900/how-can-i-start-a-process-with-a-different-name)

> `bash -c "exec -a <MyProcessName> <Command>"`
>
> Then you can kill the process with:
>
> `pkill -f MyProcessName`

Comment: I'm trying this with nodejs and it doesn't work, process name is always `node`.  I'm using this `exec -a myprocess node server.js`. I can't get anything by using `pidof myprocess` and `pgrep myprocess`. However when I try to find the name of the process by the process ID I get `node`

Comment: The same problem. -a does not set the name. no error but nor name.