# How to run a process with a custom name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to run a process with a customized name like labeling it? so if i want to kill the process it will be easy to find it with that specific name or label.

Here is my code that find any process by a given name:

```
def findProcessIdByName(processName):
    '''
    findProcessIdByName('python')
    Get a list of all the information of a specific process
    '''

    listOfProcessObjects = []

    #Iterate over all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       try:
           pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'create_time'])
           # Check if process name contains the given name string.
           # pinfo['path'] = psutil.Process(pinfo['pid']).cmdline()
           if processName.lower() in pinfo['name'].lower() :
               listOfProcessObjects.append(pinfo)
       except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied , psutil.ZombieProcess) :
           pass

    return listOfProcessObjects
```

For example if i tried to run my application:

`python manage.py runserver -h 192.168.0.110 -p 5050`

If I tried to find that running process PID by the process name 'python' it will gives me yet another processes as it shows under all the process name are **python**:

```
findProcessIdByName('python')

# Results
[ 
   { 
      'create_time':1571059481.29,
      'name':'python',
      'pid':9441
   },
   { 
      'create_time':1571059730.89,
      'name':'python',
      'pid':9889
   },
   { 
      'create_time':1571061314.85,
      'name':'python',
      'pid':13297
   },
   { 
      'create_time':1571062673.5,
      'name':'python',
      'pid':17716
   },
   { 
      'create_time':1571062674.62,
      'name':'python',
      'pid':17721 # This one is that running process
   }
]
```

By running `bash -c "exec -a myapp python manage.py runserver -h 192.168.0.110"` it gives this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
>     import werkzeug.serving
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug'
> ```

Answer (score -3):

What environment are you running this on? You may be able to use this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957732/6120578) to start your process with a specific name

Comment: I am running the app on Debian 10 using virtualenv!

Comment: By this `bash -c "exec -a <MyProcessName> <Command>"` it will gives a couple of errors where some libraries not found!

Comment: Mind posting your errors? & Have you activated the virtualenv before running?

Comment: Yes its already activated, i've provided the error in the answer

Comment: Try running `exec -a <Name> python manage.py runserver -h 192.168.0.110 -p 5050` after activating your virtualenv, the prepended bash may be refreshing a bashrc that's not your virtualenvs

Comment: Very strange! nothing happened, in fact, the command shutting the terminal off!!

Comment: Hm, sorry! I'm unsure whats going on -- you can also try bringing in this dependency then https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255466/6120578

Comment: Oh yeah, i've tried this package, its not compatible with python3, while importing it gives this error `undefined symbol: Py_InitModule3`