# How to give a name to a command inside shell_exec()?

Tags: php, shell

I am working in the Laravel framework where I am using `shell_exec()`. I am creating the string of command as in the following example.

```
 $cmd = "php artisan serve:setup";
 $resp = shell_exec($cmd);
```

How can I put a name to the above command? It shows in the system monitor as only "php"; I have multiple commands like this. I need to access the `PID` of that command and also the status of that command.

The command is running successfully, and in the system monitor, it shows the process name as "PHP".

I need process name with `exec()` or `shell_exec()` from PHP.

I have tried like this:

```
 $cmd = "bash -c exec ServerCPP -a cd $path && php artisan serve:setup 2>&1";
 $resp = shell_exec($cmd);
 dd($resp);
```

It gives the error: "Could not open input file: artisan."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start a process with a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130229/start-a-process-with-a-name)

Comment: FTR: This has nothing to do with PHP and depends only on OS facilities to change the process title.

Comment: @Peter, I am using php function to run this command it is from the code.

Comment: Add `&& echo $! ` at the end of your command. This will output the pid on the last line. You might have to trim() the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt needs to be corrected:

- `cd` first and quote the path in case the `$path` variable contains spaces
- quotes around the command executed with `bash -c`
- `exec -a ServerCPP` if you want to give the name `ServerCPP` to your process

```
$cmd = "cd '$path' && bash -c 'exec -a ServerCPP php artisan serve:setup' 2>&1";
$resp = shell_exec($cmd);
dd($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to create a command.

```
php artisan make:command ServeSetup
```

Once the file is generated, set the name of your command in `app/Console/Commands`.

```
protected $signature = 'serve:setup';
```

Hope this [helps](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands).

Comment: i want to name it from what is in $cmd which i want to run in shell_exec(). The answer you told i already knows that.